# Doxygen: how to write log output to file?

Tags: logging, doxygen

I run Doxygen from the console, and get a lot of warnings and error messages for my project. For convenience, I want Doxygen to write this log output to a file. 
How do I specify a file for the log output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to edit the Doxyfile and search for

`WARN_LOGFILE           =`

there you add the outputfile e.g. `"DoxygenWarningLog.txt"` and you are done